# how to use global variable and update it in other method

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
public int userID;
//global variable 
        
        
        public Index()
        {
            userID = 10;
            return userID;
        }
        
        public TaskCompleted()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Index())
        }
```

i want the userID to be accessed in each and every method and can we updated anywhere

Comment: Use an abstract class with either an abstract or virtual property

Comment: For the record, there is no such thing as a "global variable" in C#. Variables have different scopes and access modifiers, and must always exist within a type.

Comment: Give way more context for what you need it. You mentioned a bit context in your tags but thats not enough. The most obvious answers will presumably be wrong in your specific setup if you don't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Index` method has two problems.

1. Syntax problem: Every method must have a return type. Either a real type like `int` or the `void` keyword.

   ```cs
   public int Index()
   ```
2. Semantic problem. At every call it sets `userID` and returns it. Why store the value in this variable? It will be replaced by a new value at the next call and could just be a local variable (i.e., a variable inside the method) or be dismissed completely. But maybe your example was simply not complete.

---

Let's try different approaches:

1. Passing value through a class field (your "global" variable).

   ```cs
   private int _userId;

   public void SetUserId() // `void` means that the method is not returning a value.
   {
       _userId = 10;
   }

   public void PrintUserId()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(_userId);
   }
   ```

   This requires you to call `SetUserId();` before calling `PrintUserId();`
2. Let the method return the value.

   ```cs
   public int GetUserId() // `int` means that the method is returning an `int` value
   {
       return 10;
   }

   public void PrintUserId()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(GetUserId());
   }
   ```
3. Combine the two previous approaches

   ```cs
   private int _userId;

   public void SetUserId() 
   {
       _userId = 10;
   }

   public int GetUserId()
   {
       return _userId;
   }

   public void PrintUserId()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(GetUserId());
   }
   ```
4. C# has a concept called "property". A property is a set of "Get" and "Set" methods, just as in the previous example, but with as special syntax.

   ```cs
   private int _userId;
   public UserId
   {
      get { return _userId; }
      set { _userId = value; }
   }

   public void PrintUserId()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(UserId);
   }
   ```

   A property having no additional logic besides assigning and returning a value can also be implemented as an auto-property.

   ```cs
   public int UserId { get; set; }  // A hidden field is automatically created.
   ```

   The caller would have to do something like this:

   ```cs
   var obj = new MyClass();
   obj.UserId = 10;
   obj.PrintUserId();
   ```

Comment: i want to assign value in different method and use the variable in diff method

Comment: My example #3 does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static property of a static class:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static int UserID {get; set;}
}
```

Usage: `var userId = Globals.UserID;`

Comment: this is not working

Comment: @Anmol "not working" is a poor description of the current state of your source code. Care to elaborate?